# POST to external URL with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know there's a Spring redirect functionality, but does anyone know if you can POST to an external URL, and then load that page?

I want to recreate this functionality in Spring:

http://jsfiddle.net/bk64U/2/ :Using this form in my browser, I post my data to an external URL, and my browser navigates me to that URL. I'd like to do this in Spring, without using any HTML/Javascript/AJAX/etc. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Further clarification: the POST must actually redirect the user to the page specified in the form action. Showing a blank page, or just getting the http response isn't enough.

```
<html>
<head> <title> Something Token Request</title> </head>
<body>
<h2> Something Token Request</h2>
<form action=https://some.external.com/site/whatever.php method="POST">
<table align=center border=1>
<tr>
<td> custid </td>
<td> <input type=text name=custid value="someuserid"> </td>
<td> This is your Something custid (required) </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> password </td>
<td> <input type=password name=password value="somepassword"> </td>
<td> This is your Something password (required) </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So... you want to post data somewhere, but you don't want to use any HTMl or javascript?  Are you trying to post to the external server from within Java on the server without displaying anything to the user? If so you should look at HttpClient. You can easily create a post using that library. If not, you should please clarify your question.

Comment: @digitaljoel I do want to display something. The form I show in the html above would take the user to a new page. I would love to do this with HttpClient if it's possible, but AFAIK you can't actually redirect a user with it. I'll update my question for clarification.

Comment: Why can't you just put that form in your page?

Comment: The form information has to be hidden from the actual user of the site. They're user entered in my example for the sake of simplicity, but in actuality they should be hidden. I'm considering doing this in AJAX, but I don't know if you could hide all the information in the javascript console.

Comment: Question makes no sense to me. `the POST must actually redirect the user to the page specified in the form action` - if the form goes to an external website as its "action" then you have no control over the page from then on. You could change the "action" to be a controller method in your Spring app maybe? Then the Spring controller does the POST to the external site and you then get the response from that site and feed it to the user via your server? That sounds like a proxy to me. Are you trying to overcome cross site restrictions by any chance? If so you should state this in the question.